# How to loop through multiple row of asp.net gridview and insert to the database?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to loop through all ASP.Net gridview rows and insert them into a database. The code I wrote for these actions is below. But the problem is saving empty data to the database.

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     f_name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBox1"));
     l_name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBox2"));
     contacts = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBox3"));

     string query = string.Format("insert into [StudentsData].[dbo].[Student_Info] values('{0}','{1}','{2}')",f_name.Text,l_name.Text,contacts.Text);
     command.CommandText = query;

     try
     {
          conn.Open();
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     finally
     {
          conn.Close();
     }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code and check your variables are not empty? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. `String.Format` does not prevent it. You need to clear this parameters with `Clear` method on every iteration of course.

Comment: Dont use string concatenation but parameterized queries to insert data in your database. Otherwise you are far open for sql injection and you can't complain if your database will be destroyed sooner or later.

Comment: There are a ton of potential capabilities, but is this a single button submit with a PostBack?  Or are you attempting to do Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Do the loop something like this (and like some others have stated, use a stored procedure with parameters):

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
   f_name = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
   //etc. 
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("yourStoredProcedure", conn))
            {
               cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_name", f_name);
               //etc.
               conn.Open();
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               conn.Close();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I did  as like as you said.but it's not working.still it's saving empty data to the database after button click.

Comment: Ok, so you'll need to do some debugging to find out what exactly is in the textbox fields when you're attempting to do the insert, etc..  For anyone here to help out further, we'll need to see the relevant parts of your markup and codebehind to get a better picture of how all these fields relate to what you're doing.